# How do you get a React Native Expo app to close on its own, and reopen from start next time user opens app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo (React Native) app in the Apple App Store.

- When it is opened and starts — I fetch a bunch of data.
- If I leave the app (but don’t technically “close” the app from the app switcher), then every time I open the app again, it opens on the same screen (the screen / components persist)
- This happens even if it’s the next day
- Ideally, after some amount of time (hours?) I would like the app to fetch data, but since the previous screen persists and the component is already mounted, I don’t know how to fetch new data
- Obviously if you manually close the app (go to app switcher and swipe up to close app) upon next open it will mount the components and fetch data...
- Is there a setting for the app to “close” on its own after a certain amount of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following tools:

- To detect when the app changes from active to backgrounded: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/appstate/
- To fetch data in the background: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/